# Create object and access it in javascript (part 2)

Tags: javascript, object

I wanted to create an object from scratch. I wanted to create properties to this object I don't know yet.

I tested this code but this is not working.

```
   var myObj = {part:[],};

    // I tried to put a value but this is not working
myObj.part[0].name = "A name";
```

At final, I want an object like this, but I want to create it on the fly

```
var myObject = {
    "part": [{
        "name": "John",
            "myAccounts": ["account0","account2", "account3", "account4"],
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "age": "35"
    }, {
        "name": "kate",
            "myAccounts": ["accountA", "accountB"],
            "lastName": "jobs",
            "age": "35"
    }] };
```

Any help ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Let's start from the beginning:

1)

```
var myObj = { part:[] };
```

This is an `object` called `myObj`. It has one `property` with a key called `part` which has a "value" of an *empty* array. The fact that's it's empty is important.

2)

```
myObj.part[0].name = "A name";
```

Why doesn't this work? It's because you're trying to access the first element (`[0]`) in an *empty* array. This is impossible. So what you need to do is add some new objects to your empty array.

3)

How you do this is up to you, but based on what you've written, let's try adding a new empty object to that empty array. The easiest way to do that is using `push`:

```
myObj.part.push({});
```

The array now has one object and we can access it using `[0]`.

4)

Let's add a name to that new object. You were right in your question.

```
myObj.part[0].name = "A name";
```

And you can check in the console by typing `myObj.part[0].name` and it should return "A name".

5)

Let's tackle `myAccounts` next. It's an array. I'm assuming that you want to add to that individually too:

```
myObj.part[0].myAccounts = [];
```

Bingo! And you can `push` to that array like you did the earlier one:

```
myObj.part[0].myAccounts.push('account0');
myObj.part[0].myAccounts.push('account1');
```

...etc.

Hope that was helpful. I do urge you to take a look at all the other beginner tutorials out there in the meantime.

Comment: Very good explanation. thanks @Andy Hope this will help a lot of people !!

Comment: @Franck, don't forget to mark one of the answers correct if you felt it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Because `myObj.part` is an empty array, `myObj.part[0]` is `undefined`.
And try to access attribute from `undefined` throws error.

You may need to use

`myObj.part.push({name: "A name"});`

to push an Object with attribute `name` with value `"A name"` into `myObj.part`.

to get the final result, you can just:

```
var myObj = {part:[],};
myObj.part.push({
   "name": "John",
   "myAccounts": ["account0","account2", "account3", "account4"],
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "age": "35"
});
```

or you can first push an empty object, then set the value by your original way:

```
myObj.part.push({});
myObj.part[0].name = "A name";
myObj.part[0].lastName = "....";
```